# Simple sum of checkboxes

Tags: google-forms

I created a form in Google Forms with three checkboxes for each question. Each group of checkboxes starts with the same repeating words (as in: Vata - xxxx, Pitta - xxxx, Kapha - xxxx). I want the total number for each one displayed at the bottom of the form, i.e. if they choose the "Vata" checkbox 10 times on the form, then "10" would be displayed at the bottom and the same for the other two checkboxes. It seems simple and probably is, but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question, but perhaps try something like:

```
=countif(C1:C25,"Vata*")  
=countif(C1:C25,"Pitta*") 
=countif(C1:C25,"Kapha*")
```

assuming your responses are returned in ColumnC of your Responses Form and the formula are below existing responses and say in cells C27, C28 and C29.